# I want to create a reusable function for click() using protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I want to create a reusable click method for the below in protractor using java script and pass the below  webelement in the above reusable method. Can someone please help on this. Similarly I am trying to create reusable functions for `sendkeys()`, `selectfromdropdown` etc. and pass the webelements as parameters.

```
var button = element(by.className('question__button'));
```

I know how to do it in selenium but not sure how to write those in protractor.

Comment: Sounds like a great project. What's your question?

Comment: i think the question is: How i can create a reusable function for click with protractor?

Comment: @ÓscarRodríguez that was exactly my question! and thanks for your answer.. it helps me :)

Comment: @Vinay im glad to ear it

Comment: Sorry this question doesnt make much sense.  `click`, `sendKeys` etc. are all prototypes of the web element aka `ElementFinder`.  But you want to create a function that will click on the WebElement you pass it.  So you basically just want `myReusableClickFunc(myElement)` instead of `myElement.click()`?  If yes.. Oscars answer below is what you want.  But again doesnt make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
function clickAny(button){
 button.click()
}
```

Comment: this is a poor answer but i dont understand well what you want

Comment: this.click = function (webElement) {
        webElement.click();
    };

Comment: this.clickWithJavaScript = function (webElement) {
        browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", webElement);
    };

Comment: this.doubleClick = function (webElement) {
        browser.actions().doubleClick(webElement).perform();
    };

Comment: this.clickWithActionsClass = function (webElement) {
        browser.actions().mouseMove(webElement).click().perform();
    };